# Facebook 3.1 SDK bundle ID , how to use same bundle ID for multiple apps

Tags: facebook

Facebook 3.1 SDK needs a bundle ID , to match with application's bundle ID.
I have more than 100 Facebook apps , so instead of giving 100 bundle id's is there a solution to use one unique id.

Is there a way to dynamically change the Facebook bundle id in dashboard using code?